# как сделать так , чтобы выбранное значение из выпадающего списка запоминалось и вносилось в базу данных после кнопки подтверждения?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
тут только код списка но дальше не пошло(

<?
include("connect.phtml");
$r= mysql_query("SELECT name_goods FROM goods") 
or die ("!1");
echo "<select name='product'>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{ 
echo "<option value='".$row['name_goods']."'>".$row['name_goods']."</option>";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, mysql-функции небезопасны и больше языком не поддерживаются. Переходите на PDO. По сути вопроса: эта часть кода, которую вы показали,  должна находиться в теге form, у которой должен быть файл-обработчик, он и должен выполнить запрос, записывающий товар в базу.

https://yandex.ru/search/?text=form%20php%20post&&lr=213